# Switching out the view embedded in a NSContainerView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a swift project, where I programatically make buttons based on the amount of devices connected to a PC (in a nutshell). All of these devices are to get their own designated view, where a user can adjust settings of this device.

What I've managed to accomplish so far, is programatically placing the buttons, and programatically create a view for each device:

```
func createView() {
    let frame : NSRect = NSMakeRect(32, 32, 200, 200)
    let view : NSView = NSView(frame: frame)
    view.wantsLayer = true
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor

    self.view = view
}
```

Now, what I did is when a button is pressed, the view corresponding to the button:

```
@objc private func switchToView(sender : OpenDeviceButton) {
    let device : Device = sender.device!
    self.view.window?.contentView = device.view
}
```

However, what I intend to do is, instead of changing everything, I'd line to only change a small part. So, what I figured out is to use a `ContainerView` and switch out the embedded content, however, I couldn't find anything within the Apple docs to help me out.

Is there a way to swap out the contents of a container view with another `NSView`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace a subview manually like so:

```
let oldView = self.view.window?.contentView!.subviews[0]
let frame = oldView.frame
oldView.removeFromSuperview()
device.view.frame = frame
self.view.window?.contentView!.addSubview(device.view)
```